# sort list with respect to words in other list

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I want to sort the words in list with respect to words in other list. Here my list contains three word string Tom Cruise Gerald and I have to re-arrange this list as per the word in Base List i.e. Gerald Tom Cruise.

Just looking for a pythonic and best way to achieve this:

My list:

```
['Tom Cruise Gerald']
```

Base list for sorting:

```
['Gerald Tom Cruise']
```

Output for My List:

```
['Gerald Tom Cruise']
```

Comment: So you have one list `[b,c,a]` and one list `[a,b,c]` and you want `[a,b,c]`? Doesn't look like a problem to me, you already got what you want. Perhaps you're not explaining it right. Also, show what you tried so far to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Marco Bonelli, i think the second list is only a sort of "alphabet". The first list could be ['a','b','c', the second ['z','y','x',....'.c','b','a'] and the output ['c','b','a']

Comment: @NyuB yeah I figured, but that's not explained very well.

Comment: Also, is that `['Tom Cruise Gerald']` a typo or you really have a list of one element?

Comment: i have a list of one element and that's a string with multiple words

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
l = ["the", "dog", "jumped"]
master = ["the", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumped", "over", "thine", "lazy", "dog"]
```

Here are our lists. In order to sort `l`, we'd normally use `l.sort()`. But look! `list.sort` accepts an argument `key`! This is a function that takes each value and outputs a number that we can use as an orderer. So let's use "the position in `master`":

```
l.sort(key=master.index)
print(l)
```

This gives us:

```
['the', 'jumped', 'dog']
```

Success!

Comment: Does it mean i have to add a step to split the string ['Tom Cruise Gerald"] as list ["tom", "cruise", "gerald"]. doesn't look like very intuitive soln

Comment: @min2bro Well, your "list" isn't actually a `list` at the moment. You've just put a string _in_ a list. Use `"Tom Cruise Gerald".split()`, not `["Tom Cruise Gerald"]`.

Comment: Note that the `list.index` method requires an average time complexity of O(n) and is therefore inherently inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

You can use dict comprehension with `enumerate` to create a keyword-to-index mapping from the reference list so that you can easily sort a given list with the mapped index that costs an average of O(1) for lookup:

```
reference = ['Gerald', 'Tom', 'Cruise']
index = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(reference)}
print(sorted(['Tom', 'Cruise', 'Gerald'], key=index.get))
```

This outputs:

```
['Gerald', 'Tom', 'Cruise']
```

Answer (score 1):

you could create a sort-dictionary for fast look-up and use that as `key`:

```
data = 'Tom Cruise Gerald'.split()
sort = 'Gerald Tom Cruise'.split()
sort_dct = {d: s for d, s in zip(data, sort)}

print(sorted(data, key=sort_dct.get))
```

or if you want that back to a `str`:

```
print(' '.join(sorted(data, key=sort_dct.get)))
```

note that `['Tom Cruise Gerald']` is a list containing one single `str` element.